# React Material UI get list item details on click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have populated the list from API response. I have an edit component to update the list item value.
I need list item values when list item clicked and pass that as props to edit component. Below is my code.

```
class Appointments extends Component {
constructor()
{
  super();
  this.state = {
    CurrentAppointments: [],
    isModalOpen: false,
    selectedLead: 
    { leadid: '', acountname: '', status:'', category:'',
          appointment:
          [
            {
              aptid: '',
              aptdate:'',
              status: ''
            }
          ]
    }
  }
      this.handleModelOpen =this.handleModelOpen.bind(this);
      this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
      this.handleRowSelected = this.handleRowSelected.bind(this);
}

  componentDidMount() {
    api.get().then(json => this.setState({ CurrentAppointments: json }));
  }

  handleModelOpen() {
    this.setState({isModalOpen: true})
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: false});
  }
  
  **handleRowSelected(item) {
    //this.setState({ selectedLead: item });
    
    console.log("Item"+ this.state.selectedLead)
    //this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
  }**
```

below is render

```
<List>
            {this.state.CurrentAppointments.map(item => (
                    <div key = {item.leadid}>
                        <ListItem button 
                        className={classes.listItem} 
                        selectedLead = {item}
                        onClick= {(item)=>this.handleRowSelected(item)}>
                        <div>
```

Comment: So I see you pass the selected `item` to `handleRowSelected`. What have you tried from there? I think you need to provide more code as I don't see where you consume the `this.state.selectedItem` value or any edit component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you are sending what returns in click of the ListItem,
not because you give it the same name, it will have the same value.
you have to do it like this.

```
{this.state.CurrentAppointments.map(item => (
    <div key = {item.leadid}>
        <ListItem button 
            className={classes.listItem} 
            selectedLead = {item}
            onClick= {(event)=>this.handleRowSelected(item)} // event is the value to click and item is the value the map
    >
    <div>
```

Comment: Hello Krlos, Thanks for quick help. How to handle the function? how to pass item values? `code` handleRowSelected(item) {

    
    console.log("Item"+ item)
  }